# Why does form submission not work after an installation of npm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, forms, npm

I created an app to analize Posts and Posters in a blog using Laravel 6. However the form submission to select a Post or a Poster doesn't work for some reasons.
I suppose the problems started after I deleted npm modules and I installed another time npm.

This is my code:

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')

    <form method="GET" id="poster_submit">
        @csrf

        <div class="form-group mt-5 col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
            <label for="select_poster" class="text-primary">Select a <b>Poster</b>:</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <select class="form-control" id="select_poster">
                        @foreach ($users as $user)
                            <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->surname . " " . $user->firstname }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-width">Go to the Poster!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <form method="GET" id="post_submit">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6 offset-sm-3 mt-5">
            <label for="select_post" class="text-danger">Select a <b>Post</b>:</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <select class="form-control" id="select_post">
                        @foreach ($posts as $post)
                            <option value="{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->id . " - " . $post->title }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-width">Go to the Post!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="application/javascript">

        $("#poster_submit").on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var poster_id = document.getElementById("select_poster");
            var id = poster_id.options[poster_id.selectedIndex].value;
            alert(id);
            window.location = "profile/" + id;
        });

        $("#post_submit").on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var post_id = document.getElementById("select_post");
            var id = post_id.options[post_id.selectedIndex].value;
            alert(id);
            window.location = "post/" + id;
        });

    </script>

@endsection
```

When I click a button nothing happens but I don't see any errors. I checked that JQuery works correctly.
When I click a button I should see an alert and then I should be redirected to another page but that doesn't happen because the form submission doesn't work.
Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure jQuery is loaded before running this code. Try wrapping this with additional code like this:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

$(function() {

    $("#poster_submit").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var poster_id = document.getElementById("select_poster");
        var id = poster_id.options[poster_id.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(id);
        window.location = "profile/" + id;
    });

    $("#post_submit").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post_id = document.getElementById("select_post");
        var id = post_id.options[post_id.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(id);
        window.location = "post/" + id;
    });

});   

</script>
```

Otherwise please include your JavaScript console log

Answer (score 0):

Since you have put

```
e.preventDefault()
```

In your submit event, it will prevent the form to submit.

Basically what you can do is you can remove the e.preventDefault() and let the form submit to a method of your controller and from within the method redirect to new URL.